# ¿Como usar $http.post y $http.get en una misma funcion?

Tags: php, angularjs, post

Hace unas semanas empecé a usar AngularJs para una aplicación del típico estilo de administración.

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Lo utilizo con PHP, mediante el método `$http.post` envió los parámetros a un archivo 'archivo.php', quien toma las variables y ejecuta una consulta sobre MySQL.

También utilizo `$http.get` para recibir arrays desde otro archivo .php.

Ahora la cuestión, ¿cómo puedo usar `$http.post` y `$http.get` en una misma función?

Supongamos que en php necesito hacer algo como esto:

```
<?php
 include('conn.php');
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

 $variable = $conn->real_escape_string($data->variable);

 $query = 'INSERT INTO datos VALUES ("'.$variable.'")';
 $conn->query($query);

 print $query;

?>
```

Necesito pasar parámetros a php, que php me ejecute lo que necesite, y que me devuelva algo "x" mediante `print`, por ende en Angular, necesito enviar los parámetros, y después recibirlos, todo del mismo archivo, ¿alguna idea?

Comment: a ver ,no se mucho de php , pero por lo que te entendi , deberias hacer endpoints a las rutas que vas a usar , algo similar a lo que ocurre en nodejs,con eso podrias hacer lo que necesitas facilmente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para detectar el método en que se realizo la solicitud puedes usar:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

Por ejemplo:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     // Logica para solicitudes POST
} else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
     // Logica para solicitudes GET
}
```

Mas info [aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php).

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.request.php) para leer los datos tanto de GET como de POST.  Luego los combinas con un is ser y tenes solucionado el problema. 
http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: hola @Barcho. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por contribuir. ¿Podrías mostrar un breve ejemplo de código de cómo usarlo? Quizás un ejemplo sea de mayor utilidad para futuros lectores.